# How does the Realm of Diggle Gods DLC affect the original game?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

How does the DLC affect existing save games? Do I have start over in order to access DLC material?

What I understood from the description is that there are new levels and items, but what I didn't quite get was that are those DLC levels some where deep down in the end of the game or something? Or is it just that next level that I access *can* be from the DLC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable/disable the expansion when you start the character, so in order to see the new content, you'd need to start a new character.

Comment: That's good to know. Maybe I should buy it right away before going any further this character.

Comment: @Tx3 Go ahead and finish your current characters. RoDG takes what's already a pretty tough game and adds 5 more floors of pain between you and the boss. You may have to go through quite a few characters before you live long enough to see the new content anyway.